# Why does Spark fail with "value write is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader [error]"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two almost identical write into db . scala statement ,however one trowing me an error the other not and i don't understand how to fix it ? any ideas ?

this statement is working

```
df_pm_visits_by_site_trn.write.format("jdbc").option("url", db_url_2).option("dbtable", "pm_visits_by_site_trn").option("user", db_user).option("password", db_pwd).option("truncate","true").mode("overwrite").save()
```

this one doesn't work and throwing me compiling error

```
df_trsnss .write.format("jdbc").option("url", db_url_2).option("dbtable", "df_trsnss")               .option("user", db_user).option("password", db_pwd).option("truncate","true").mode("overwrite").save()
```

> _dev.scala:464: value write is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader [error]
>   df_trsnss.write.format("jdbc").option("url",
>   db_url_2).option("dbtable", "trsnss").option("user",
>   db_user).option("password",
>   db_pwd).option("truncate","true").mode("overwrite").save()

if i delete my second write statement or just simply comment it out whole code is compiling with no errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the error message, `df_trsnss` is a DataFrameReader, not a DataFrame. You likely forgot to call `load`.

> val df_trsnss = spark.read.format("csv")

instead of

> val df_trsnss = spark.read.format("csv").load("...")